# I want a to create automatically a php file that runs on server automatically

Tags: php, cron

I want to create automatically a php file that will created and run on server automatically, and then after some specified time it will reloaded.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: create a webpage that will be reloaded by javascript, or a background ajax request will certain intervals will do(but again please elaborate your question)

Comment: You already tagged this "cron" but could not figure out how they work or form a more specific question about them? -1

Answer (score 3):

Use cron jobs for this.

Cron job is executing on specified time. Cron job is a php file.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Comment: thanks guys,I elaborate my question here:


Main problem is how to create a php file automatically and run it on server for some time? Like when i load abc.php file in my browser it will first create a xyz.php file on server and run it on server side for some specific time and when time completes it will reloads the abc.php file.

Comment: Create a php file (cron job) and put content in that to create another php file and write content into that. May be this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to create automatically php files with code in there =)

But in terms of execution U should **create a cronjob** on that php file (on server where it lays and set the period of time for execution, say every 1hour), here is the code U then need to execute:

```
<?php
sleep(5); // for 5 sec
header('Location: filename.php'); // reloading on filename.php
?>
```

Comment: Ok tell me how to execute a php file automatically on server?

Comment: On Your Linux/Unix server U should set the cronTab (Cron Table) it's a deamon wich lives there all the time, for example in a cron file U need to create something like * 1 * * * /path/to/filename.php where every * is minutes, hours, days, months, day-of-week. U can also search many interesting articles about this matter in google type something like "set crontab on linux".